# How do I load data from mysql database to my form fields in grails?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a problem, I can't seem to load data from DB to my gsp form fields. If I have the following like:

```
rates.gsp
<html>
...
<body>
<g:form action="loadPay" controller="rates" name="ratesForm" class="cssForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Pay Idd:</label></td>
      <td><g:textField name="payId"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Pay Description:</label></td>
      <td><g:textField name="payDesc"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
   <g:submitButton name="Add" formaction="loadPay"/>
</g:form>
</body>
</html>

PayController.groovy

def loadPay{
   //get the data from DB using HQL
}
```

From my example above, how do I populate the textfields with data from my database. What should I do in the controller so that when I click submit from my gsp I will be able to load DB data to forms? (I'm new to grails.)

Comment: What data do you need? what is the domain structure? what have you tried? If you give the detail of the problem then someone can give you direction.

Comment: First read grails basics,

Comment: Need to see the code in your controller method. Also, why are you using HQL and not Grails domain model?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I already figured this a couple of days ago. I used this kind of code in my gsp:

`<g:if test="${pay!=null  && pay.payDesc != null }">
    <tr>
        <td><label>Pay description:</label></td>
        <td><g:textField name="${pay.payDesc}"/></td>
    </tr>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Pay description:</label></td>
        <td><g:textField name="payDesc"/></td>
    </tr>
</g:else>`
Although I'm not sure if this is a good way of displaying data from DB to my gsp. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to show the db data while editing the form ??If you want to instantly populate the form then u can use JQUERY AJAX. I did not get what exactly you want to do. So if you elaborate your problem I can provide you a solution.